# When I tried to install AgnesGraph, I got an error

Tags: agens-graph

I want to install the *AgensGraph*.

But when I tried to install *AgensGraph*, I got an error. The installation commands and errors are as follows.

- installation command:

```
git clone git@github.com:bitnine-oss/agens-graph.git
```

- installation error:

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
>
> RSA key fingerprint is MD5:16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the github SSH link. SSH requires an authentication via a SSH key and a passphrase. If you have no affiliation to this organisation clone via HTTPS

```
git clone https://github.com/bitnine-oss/agens-graph.git
```

resulting into:

```
Cloning into 'agens-graph'...
remote: Counting objects: 11484, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
Rremote: Total 11484 (delta 123), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 11295
Receiving objects: 100% (11484/11484), 24.74 MiB | 193.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6006/6006), done.
Checking out files: 100% (4879/4879), done.
```

Further links:

- https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/
- https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols